# Is it possible to train on multiple images sizes in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

Keras takes numpy arrays as input for training data, however it is possible to create models that can take variable input sizes. I'm wondering if there is a way to incorporate images of various dimensions in the training data for a model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give variable size images to train a model in Keras. According to Keras API, the `Input` layer function looks as follows.

```
Input(shape=(3,None,None))
```

Where, `3` is presenting number of channels for RGB images. But you have to clearly tell Keras, what is the width and height of the training images. So, there is no way Keras can handle variable length images.

So, you have to transform the images to a specific size first and then train model using Keras.

Comment: This is correct when working with Theano backend, but when using Tensorflow backend, shape has to be: shape=(None, None, 3)